# Gesture to repeat invisible recaptcha audio challenge while using TalkBack

Tags: talk-back

When I am on an invisible recaptcha audio challenge (see image below) and I am using Google TalkBack is there a gesture to repeat the voice saying the numbers? When I press the play button focus seems to go to the textfield below and TalkBack describes the change of focus at the same time with the recaptcha voice saying the audio challenge making it difficult for me to hear both voices at the same time and solve the 'puzzle'.

When I use VoiceOver on Mac, if I press ctrl button, the recaptcha voice repeats the audio challenge and I can solve the puzzle without having to hear both voices simultaneously.

Is there a gesture for TalkBack to repeat the challenge without moving the focus somewhere else?

[image]